# sforce.connection.remoteFunction() response "double" double quoted?

Tags: platform-bug, ajax-toolkit

I'm making a callout to a REST Resource using the sforce.connection.remoteFunction() and getting a strange result.

My RestResource returns a String.

@RestResource(urlMapping='/demo/*')

```
global class DF_RestDemo {

    @HttpPost
    global static String doPost(Id contactId) {
        return 'testing';
    }
}
```

But in my onSuccess function the String has been double double quoted:
[image: Chrome debugger result]

Is this a known issue?  I can't seem to find anything about it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When apex rest request to `/services/apexrest/[namespace/]demo`  is made it is returning the response of type string which results `"testing"` not this `testing` and this response in javascript treat as string which will again append the response within `""` which results the output `""testing""`.

So workaround of this is to return the response `use wrapper class` in the form of json instead of string.

I hope this information will help you.